# What is the most efficient solution to paginate a JSP application without heavy coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp, pagination

I'm looking for the easiest solution to create pagination for a JSP app without too much hassle. Is it even possible to create pagination on client-side with dynamic mysql content? Using JSP, I tried taglib which never worked... I found JSP pagination tutorials on `opentutorials.com` but... Nothing I could really wrap my head around quite easily... So far what I found over the web just don't quite work or other solutions like open tutorials are too bulky and required heavy coding... I'm looking for something light weight... I tried `Displaytag` but I do not want to use tables to display product listings. I prefer `divs`. I don't mind using `javascript` or `jquery`... I have no clue how to paginate my app... `:/`

I`m trying to paginate the category page below.

```
<div class="middle_container_category">
                <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:large; margin-top:2%; margin-bottom:2%;"> ${selectedCategory.name} </div>
                <hr class="horizontal_line" >
                <div style="width:100%; ">
                </div>

                <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">
                <div id="product_container" class="lazyload">

                <div class="product_img_container">
                    <div id="product_image"><a href="viewProduct?${product.id}">
                                    <img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" /></a></div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="product_name_container">
                                        <div id="product_name"><a class="category_links" href="viewProduct?${product.id}">${product.name}</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="product_price_container">
                                        <div id="product_price">$${product.price}</div></div>

                    <div id="button_wrapper_category">
                    <div id="add_toList"><form id="wishlistForm" action="addToWishlist" method="post">
              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">

              <input id="submit_list" class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit">
            </form></div>

                    <div id="add_toCart"><form id="cartForm" action="addToCart" method="post">


              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
              <input id="submit_cart" class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">


                        </form></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </c:forEach>


            </div>
```

Comment: use jquery to hit backend selrvlet and get the data, and replace your <div style="width:100% with the new content got from the servlet using JQUERY, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with using tables if you are going to use them to show tabulated data and not to style your web up (using them to align, etc).
A very simple and useful library is DataTables: https://www.datatables.net/.
It supports AJAX querying, pagination, filtering you can set any style you want and it is simple to use.